# Build html table from filtered Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, html-table, outlook, html-email

I need a little help as I'm trying to insert a filtered Excel table in a open Outlook email message.
I've managed to do that using a function I found online (ExcelRangeToOutlookEmailBody), but that replaces the message I had before pasting the table and I'm also unable to add any text above or below the table, so now I'm trying to write a sub that dynamically creates a html table, as this seems easier to manipulate in order to insert text before and after the table.

I have a table with a number of projects attributed to a number of persons, and I want to filter the table by each person, copy the visible rows and paste it to an open e-mail message. I want to just press a button to Excel create several (usually less than 10) email messages with the filtered table.

The code I have is a mix of things I found online plus some tweaking of mine, and it builds the html table dynamically. However, it only works for the first person and it fails to build the html table from then on - it just repeats the first filtered table. To simplify things, the code below it's just the html table builder, the rest I got figured out (or so I believe).

```
Sub HtmlTableBuilder()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsBD As Worksheet
Dim Table As ListObject
Dim TableMail As ListObject
Dim Col As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim finalTable As Range
Dim result As Variant
Dim values As Variant
Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim valCounter As Long
Dim rngHdr As Range
Dim rngDat As Range

Set Wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsb")
Set ws = Wb.Worksheets("FL")
Set wsBD = Wb.Worksheets("BD")                                                  'Person database
Set Table = ws.ListObjects("TabMail")                                           'Table to be filtered, copied and pasted to email
Set TableMail = wsBD.ListObjects("People")                                      'Table with names, ID and emails of each person
Set Col = Range("TabMail[PersonID]")                                            'Column with the IDs
Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary                                              ' Add reference to MS Scripting Runtime

'Extract all person names from an array

 values = ws.Range("G5:G1000").Value2                                           'Value2 is faster than Value
 dic.CompareMode = BinaryCompare                                                'Set the comparison mode to case-sensitive

 For valCounter = LBound(values) To UBound(values)                              'Loop to extract name of persons
    If Not dic.Exists(values(valCounter, 1)) Then                               'Check if the name is already in the dictionary
        dic.Add values(valCounter, 1), 0                                        'Add the new name as key, with a dummy value of 0
    End If
 Next valCounter

 result = dic.Keys                                                              'Extract the dictionary's keys as a 1D array
 count = UBound(result)                                                         'number of persons

'Filter a table by a person name a build a html table with the visible data to send via email
i = 0
 Do While i <= count - 1
    With Range("A4")                                                            'table first cell is A4; count = number of persons
        Col.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=result(i)                           'filters table by person i
        Set rng = Table.HeaderRowRange                                          'gets the table header
        Set rngHdr = rng.Resize(, 6)                                            'discards last column
        Set rng = Table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)           'gets table visible celss
        Set rngDat = rng.Resize(, 6)                                            'discards last column
        Set finalTable = Union(rngHdr, rngDat)                                  'joins header and body
        
        'loop to build html tables
        
        R = 0                                                                   'initializes row counter
            If finalTable.Rows.count > 1 Then                                   'condition to check if filtered table isn't empty
                htmlstr = "<table border=1 style='border-collapse: collapse'>"  'html string start
                For Each rngrow In finalTable.Rows                              'loop rows
                    c = 0: R = R + 1                                            'Initializes row & column counter
                    htmlstr = htmlstr & "<tr>"                                  'html string row beginning
                    For Each rngcol In finalTable.Columns                       'loop columns to each row
                        c = c + 1
                        rngvalue = finalTable(R, c).Value
                         If R = 1 Then                                          'checks if is first row to format as header
                            htmlstr = htmlstr & "<th>" & rngvalue & "</th>"
                        Else                                                    'formats as body row
                            htmlstr = htmlstr & "<td>" & rngvalue & "</td>"
                        End If
                    Next rngcol
                 htmlstr = htmlstr & "</tr>"                                    'html string row ending
                Next rngrow
                htmlstr = htmlstr & "</table>"                                  'html string table ending
            End If
        Debug.Print htmlstr                                                     'Debug to output results to immediate window
    End With
    
    i = i + 1
 
 Loop

End Sub
```

Below is the table (TableMail) that I need to filter by person ID. Note that this table is linked to another table in another worksheet where it gets all it's values except the deadline, which the user needs to enter.
Blank cells in the last three rows are not really empty, they contain the same formulas as the other cells, I just have some conditional formatting on blank cells. The formulas are similar to this one:  =IF(MyWorkbook.xlsb!TabMail[@[Project_ID]]="";"";"All")

```
| Table     | Project_ID    | Task Assigned     | Qtty 1    | Qyy2  | Deadline          | PersonID  |
|---------- |------------   |---------------    |--------   |------ |-----------------  |---------- |
| Project2  | 790403        | All               | 20        | 30    | 06/01/24 13:00    | 104       |
| Project2  | 790536        | All               | 40        | 50    | 06/01/24 13:00    | 104       |
| Project1  | 790539        | All               | 2         | 0     | 06/01/24 13:00    | 104       |
| Project2  | 790661        | All               | 224       | 1,2   | 09/02/24 13:00    | 104       |
| Project1  | 790685        | All               | 1         | 0     | 09/02/24 13:00    | 103       |
| Project1  | 790977        | All               | 0         | 19,8  | 09/02/24 13:00    | 103       |
| Project2  | 799103        | All               | 299       | 4,8   | 09/02/24 13:00    | 103       |
| Project1  | 799372        | All               | 35        | 0,6   | 06/01/24 13:00    | 102       |
| Project1  | 799420        | All               | 0         | 87    | 06/01/24 13:00    | 102       |
| Project1  | 790691        | All               | 56        | 40,2  | 06/01/24 13:00    | 101       |
| Project1  | 790864        | All               | 15        | 0,6   | 09/02/24 13:00    | 101       |
| Project1  | 790907        | All               | 267       | 3,6   | 09/02/24 13:00    | 101       |
|           |               |                   |           |       | xx/xx/24  13:00   |           |
|           |               |                   |           |       | xx/xx/24  13:00   |           |
|           |               |                   |           |       | xx/xx/24  13:00   |           |
```

There is also a second table mentioned in the code (People):

```
| PersonID  | Name      | MAIL                                  | Step1     | Step2     |
|---------- |---------- |-------------------------------------  |-------    |-------    |
| 95        | Bart      | blablablabla@gmail.com                | ide3      | idv2      |
| 96        | Maggie    | dummy.dummy@gmail.com                 | ide4      | idv3      |
| 97        | Lisa      | fake_fake@gmail.com                   | ide8      | idv1      |
| 98        | Homer     | placeholder@gmail.com                 | ide3      | idv5      |
| 99        | Marge     | notimportant@outlook.com              | ide5      | idv4      |
| 100       | Flanders  | noneofyoubusiness@iol.com             | ide2      |           |
| 101       | Peter     | nomorefunnynames@gmail                | ide1      |           |
| 102       | Lois      | ranoutofjokes@outlook.com             | ide11     |           |
| 103       | Meg       | wastingtoomuchtimewiththis@gmai.com   | ide9      |           |
| 104       | Chris     | lackingimagination@gmail.com          | ide6      |           |
| 105       | Brian     | gladitsover@gmail.com                 | ide7      |           |
```

Here's the output of the above code

I have IDs of 4 persons, but this loop always outputs this same table, instead of one table for each person:

```
| Project   | Project_ID    | Task Assigned     | Qtty 1    | Qtty 2    | Deadline              |
|---------- |------------   |---------------    |--------   |--------   |-------------------    |
| Project2  | 790403        | All               | 20        | 30        | 06/01/24 13:00:00     |
| Project2  | 790536        | All               | 40        | 50        | 06/01/24 13:00:00     |
| Project1  | 790539        | All               | 2         | 0         | 06/01/24 13:00:00     |
| Project2  | 790661        | All               | 224       | 1,2       | 09/02/24 13:00:00     |
```

The problem seems to be when I assemble the header and the body of the table:

```
Set finalTable = Union(rngHdr, rngDat)
```

I've checked and both rngHdr and rngDat seem OK, but finalTable only seems to contain the header which is strange because it outputs the previous person projects.

I am now stuck here not really understanding why the loop only works on its first pass.

The rest of the code seems to work fine, it does filter the TableMail sequentially by each Person ID and with my complete code I do get the information I need from the second People table and am able to open 4 new email messages, each with the right recipient, subject and salutation, and I am also able to concatenate the table with the rest of the email text. I just don't understand why it keeps pasting the same first filtered table.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: `If finalTable.Rows.count > 1 Then` this test only returns true if the first `Area` of `finalTable` has >1 row.  Since you don't clear `htmlstr` between iterations, you always get the one table for which the test passes.

Comment: Try instead using `If finalTable.Cells.Count > finalTable.Rows(1).Cells.Count Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single table to illustrate and breaking down the functionality into separate methods where I think it makes sense:

```vb
Sub HtmlTableBuilder()

    Dim Wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Table As ListObject, Col As ListColumn, html As String
    Dim dic As Object, rngDat As Range, rngVis As Range, k
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsb")
    Set ws = Wb.Worksheets("FL")
    Set Table = ws.ListObjects("TabMail")     'Table to be filtered
    Set Col = Table.ListColumns("PersonID")   'Column with the IDs
    
    Set dic = UniquesFromRange(Col.DataBodyRange) 'get unique values

    For Each k In dic.Keys    'loop over dictionary keys
        Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=Col.Index, Criteria1:=k
        Set rngVis = Table.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        html = AsHtmlTable(rngVis)
        If Len(html) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print html
            Debug.Print "---------------------"
        Else
            Debug.Print "No rows for " & k 'should never happen....
        End If
    Next k
    Table.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
End Sub

'Convert a range `rng` to html
'  `rng` should include headers on row#1: if only one row then no html is created
Function AsHtmlTable(rng As Range) As String
    Dim html As String, rw As Range, c As Range, tag As String
    If rng.Cells.count = rng.Rows(1).Cells.count Then Exit Function 'nothing to build...
    html = "<table border=1 style='border-collapse: collapse'>"
    tag = "th" 'headers to start....
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        html = html & "    <tr>"
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            html = html & "<" & tag & ">" & c.Value & "</" & tag & ">"
        Next c
        html = html & "</tr>" & vbLf
        tag = "td" 'regular td for rest of rows
    Next rw
    AsHtmlTable = html & "</table>"
End Function

'return a dictionary object with all unique values from `rng`
Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim c As Range, tmp
    Set UniquesFromRange = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    UniquesFromRange.CompareMode = 0 'vbBinaryCompare: case-insensitive
    For Each c In rng.Cells
       tmp = Trim(c.Value)
       If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If Not UniquesFromRange.Exists(tmp) Then UniquesFromRange.Add tmp, 1
       End If
    Next c
End Function
```

Comment: This works perfectly, although I don't want the final column PersonID in the html table, so I added two lines to achieve this _Columns("G").Hidden = True_ and _Columns("G").Hidden = False_
There are probably more elegant and optimal solutions to achieve this, but it does work